# Калькулятор неправильно считает месяца и дни JS

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь написать программку , которая будет считать сколько тебе лет, месяцев и дней (например: тебе 20 лет, 2 месяца и 10 дней). Но считается как-то странно в днях и месяцах. В чем тут ошибка?

```
 function calculateAge(){
        let currentDate = new Date();
        let day = document.getElementById("date").value;
        let month = document.getElementById("month").value ;
        let year = document.getElementById("year").value;
        let expectedDate = new Date(`${year}/${month}/${day}`);
        let timeLeft = ( currentDate - expectedDate);
        let d1 = Math.floor(timeLeft / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) % 30),
        m1 = Math.floor(timeLeft / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30) % 12),
        y1 = Math.floor(timeLeft / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365));
        document.querySelector('.for-years').innerHTML = y1;
        document.querySelector('.for-days').innerHTML = d1;
        document.querySelector('.for-months').innerHTML = m1;   
    }
```